# Having trouble using printf for decimal value output wsl , awk , and printf / bash

Tags: awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
} 
FS=","
}

/[0-9][0-9][0-9]?[,][o][n][l]/ { onlavg+=$2/5 }

END {
print"\n"
print "Section Average" "\n"
printf "online "(%d.2f,onlavg);
}
```

Here is the field data being used:

```
Final Grade,Section 
95,online
100,online 
100,onsite
72,online
65,online
88,onsite
91,onsite
82,online
80,onsite
```

The code is supposed to take either the online students grade average or the onsite students grade The output comes out to 82.8 but im supposed to format it two decimal places to 82.80 I know its simple, I just never worked with bash to this extent and I've never used

I am calculating an average but I need the output to be 82.80 not just 82.8. What am I doing wrong? I am using WSL and its bash as my shell to run this. Also, how do I get a count instead of the "5" Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Kindly do add these samples in your question, comments are not meant to add samples/codes, thank you.

Comment: I used:
    printf  "Online: %d.0", onlavg
It seemed to work! 
Any insights?

Comment: Insight - you haven't read the awk man page on how to use printf and so are trying to guess at some way it might work but getting it wrong. Just read the awk man page for [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf) and do what it says there.

Comment: Thanks for the not so helpful answer. Also, my first programming class (turbo pascal) was taught by a Mr. Morton way back in the early 90's

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="," }
FNR>1 && ($2=="online" || $2=="onsite"){
  count++
  sum+=$1
}
END{
  printf("Total Avg= %.02f\n",count!=""?(sum/count):"NA")
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
printf "online "(%d.2f,onlavg)
```

is not how one uses `printf` in GNU `AWK`. If you want to use `printf` first argument is string with format specifiers, then list of values to place, for example

```
awk 'END{printf "%d is bigger than %d", 100, 99}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
100 is bigger than 99
```

Also `%d.2f` is in fact `%d` specifer followed by `.2f` rather than specifier as whole, so if you do `printf "%d.2f", 55.5` you will get `55.2f`, correct specifier for float with 2 digits after `.` is `%.2f` for example `printf "%.2f", 55.5` gives `55.50`. Finally if you want to use same format for all numbers in output you might elect to set `OFMT` (Output ForMaT) and use `print` rather than `printf` for example

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.2f"}END{print 10.5, "is bigger than", 9.5}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
10.50 is bigger than 9.50
```

*(all examples tested in gawk 4.2.1)*